# 'encuesta' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: django

The following shows properly the Items on Admin when adding a new (Encuesta)

example: Brasil vs. Chile

But when i click save it shows the following

'encuesta' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

```
return unicode("%s Vs. %s) % (self.equipoA, self.equipoB)
```

I changed the following to this but nothing happened either

```
class encuesta(models.Model):

equipoA = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoA')
golesEquipoA = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, blank=True)
equipoB = models.ForeignKey(equipo, related_name='equipo_equipoB')
golesEquipoB = models.IntegerField(max_length=2,blank=True)

ETAPA = (
    ('1', 'Octavos De Final'),
    ('2', 'Cuartos De Final'),
    ('3', 'Semifinal'),
    ('4', 'Final'),
    ('5', '3ra Posicion')
)

etapa = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=ETAPA)
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)

def __unicode__(self):

    return "%s Vs. %s" % (self.equipoA, self.equipoB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you need **unicode** to return str (not an object).

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s Vs. %s" % (unicode(self.equipoA), unicode(self.equipoB))
```